# Dynamic redirect in ASP.Net using C#

Tags: asp.net

I have the following inputs to address the problem.

1. A Master page that has a drop down (ID:dd1). The dropdown is populated when the master page is loaded.
2. An ASP.Net page that uses master page as defined in point # 1. This page has a dropdown control and has list of the allowed actions that a user can perform. This dropdown (say ID:dd2) is populated based on the selection made in the dropdown of the master page. The dropdown (ID:dd2) has list of the actions that a user can perform.
3. When an item is selected from dropdown (ID: dd2), the user is redirected to the different ASP.Net page that corresponds to the action selected from dd2 (I have already written the code to retrieve redirect path from the XML document for items selected from the dropdown dd2).

Question - How to perform the cross page post back on the target page(As retrieved from the XML file) for each action selected from the dropdown dd2 and retrieve the values on the target page. Please provide the pseudo code to achieve this functionality.

Appreciate your assistance.

Thanks,
Yagya

Comment: An an alternate approach to posting back ... have you considered using AJAX for this?

Comment: Yes. AJAX was considered as one of the approach. However the same approach was declined by the client due to the security reasons.